# PHP 5.3 OOP need answer

Tags: php, oop

Please tell me why:

```
class ClassOne {
    protected $a = 10;

    public function changeValue($b) {
        $this->a = $b;
    }
}

class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
    protected $b = 10;

    public function changeValue($b) {
        $this->b = 10;
        parent::changeValue($this->a + $this->b);
    }

    public function displayValues() {
        print "a: {$this->a}, b: {$this->b}\n";
    }
}

$obj = new ClassTwo();

$obj->changeValue(20);
$obj->changeValue(10);    
$obj->displayValues();
```

Prints `a: 30` and `b: 10`.

I would appreciate an elaborate response. Thank you :)

On a side note: This is actually an exam question I've looked over and did not quite understand it. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: It's your homework? What do you expect in output?

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Also could be interesting for you: this script will have same output with any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to summarize this execution besides "it's executing the logic as you've written".

I've added comments to each call to show the intermediary steps:

```
$obj = new ClassTwo(); // a = 10, b = 10

$obj->changeValue(20); // Sets b = 10, a = 20 (a = 10 + 10 = 20)
$obj->changeValue(10); // Sets b = 10, a = 30 (a = 20 + 10 = 30)
                                                   ^
                                                   Previous value of a
$obj->displayValues();
```

You may be confused by this:

```
public function changeValue($b) {
    $this->b = 10;
    parent::changeValue($this->a + $this->b);
}
```

Because `$b` is never assigned to anything. So it doesn't matter what you pass to `changeValue`, you'll always get `30, 10` when you call `changeValue` twice.

E.g. :

```
$obj->changeValue(0); 
$obj->changeValue(0);
```

Will still output `a: 30 and b: 10`

Comment: Not downvoter, but the answer's missing one detail: `$this->b` is never changed in the code.

Comment: @meze - True, good point. I glanced over this fact by mentioning that `$b` in the parameter list is unused, since I do not know if the function's correct logic was to modify `$this->b`.

Comment: @nickb I've accepted your answer for the effort put in to format it and make a clear explanation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The parameter passed to `changeValue()` is unused.

Each call to the method results in adding `$this->a + $this->b` but you are never using the value passed in either in assigning to `a` or `b` or using it in your addition.

Basically each call to `changeValue()` adds 10 to `$this->a`.

Comment: I don't like reputation farmers.

Comment: it's users who trying up their "reputation" on silly questions.

Comment: @OZ so what your like robin hood? You go around assessing answers on easy 'silly' questions and down vote perfectly fine answers if the user has too much reputation?

Comment: @user12345613, no, I'm not so hateful.

Comment: There are no silly questions, only silly comments. (I don't really believe this, but the original question isn't silly, just perhaps based on a mistaken premise.)

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you expect, but please note that ClassTwo->changeValue doesn't use the $b parameter... (I am sure someone is going to say this isn't the answer, and it isn't, but it should be a big enough hint to figure out the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function changeValue($b) {
    $this->b = 10;
    parent::changeValue($this->a + $this->b);
  }
```

$this->b **!=** $b as argument of changeValue function
Maybe this confused you.